# JSR223 PreProcessor ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to implement the code below in JMeter with JSR223 preprocessor, however facing the mentioned issue in title.

```
public class G2bApiServletReturns extends GstUtil 
{

 GstUtil gstutil = new GstUtil();
 //generate EK using SEK in Auth response

 String 
 SEK="L+Aafhigkjkvw6qkk3XT5TTQ4MbzEpjF+VoVHye8QFyq04bdtGOjvuHWvq3WQLfm";

 byte[] EK = gstutil.decodeBase64StringTOByte(SEK);

String payload="Hello;

//Encrypted Payload



 String encoded_json = GstUtil.encodeBase64String(payload);

 String encrypted_json = gstutil.encrypt(encoded_json, EK);

 //HMAC Value

 String hmac = gstutil.generateHmac(encoded_json, EK);


}
log.info(hmac);
```

this is the error-

```
Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hmac for class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the class declaration:

```
 GstUtil gstutil = new GstUtil();
 //generate EK using SEK in Auth response
 String SEK="L+Aafhigkjkvw6qkk3XT5TTQ4MbzEpjF+VoVHye8QFyq04bdtGOjvuHWvq3WQLfm";
 byte[] EK = gstutil.decodeBase64StringTOByte(SEK);
 String payload="Hello;
//Encrypted Payload                         
 String encoded_json = GstUtil.encodeBase64String(payload);
 String encrypted_json = gstutil.encrypt(encoded_json, EK);                         
 //HMAC Value
 String hmac = gstutil.generateHmac(encoded_json, EK);
 log.info(hmac);
```

Comment: Hey,thanks.tried this solution but facing unexpected token: log @ line 292, column 1.
   log.info(hmac);

Comment: @poojapatil it's probably another unclosed brackets `{}` you have before code you showed